# SwiftUI idealWidth - how to set idealWidth and keep responsive?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui

Goal: set responsive idealWidths.

What I did:

[image]//

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(idealWidth: 100)
                //.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(idealWidth: 200)
               // .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(idealWidth: 300)
               // .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.yellow)
                .frame(idealWidth: 400)
               // .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)

        }
    }
}



#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The problem is that:

A- When I disable fixedSize. the shapes ate divided equally.
//.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)

B- When I enable fixedSize. the shapes are divided equally, but are not responsive. Ex, If I resize the MacOS window, it. won't scale accordingly to defined idealWidths.
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)

How can I set idealWidths so that its responsive?

Comment: What is the desirable behaviour?

Comment: the rectangles should render with the defined idealWidth, not all equal.
Goal is to be able to store frames width of a view (JSON for example), and load again exactly as it was saved. If I save with "width", the frames are hardcoded and not responsive. If saved with geomettry.width.0.2 for example, the amount of cells per row are also hardcoded. So idealWidth seems the best candidate

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"? If you want to "load again exactly as it was saved", then of course the widths won't change. Actually, why are you storing widths in the first place? Are the widths controlled by the user (like in an `HSplitView`) or something? This is still lacking a lot of context.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve responsive behavior while maintaining ideal widths for your rectangles, you can use a combination of GeometryReader and GeometryProxy along with flexible layout constraints.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 10)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 10 * 2)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 10 * 3)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 10 * 4)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```